# How to Insert into third table on conflict of two tables composite key in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, insert, constraints

There is a **staging table active_data_staging** which gets truncated and inserted every 5 mins, but many records in this are already there in the **final table active_data**. Hence, to only ingest my **final table active_data** with new records from **active_data_staging table**, I run the insert query on conflict of a composite key.

Now, a requirement has come, where I need to only get the fresh rows which comes every 5 mins to a third table active_data_fresh, which will be truncated and inserted with only new data at the same refresh frequency.

**Example**:

**Present**: My Staging has 145 rows (130 old, 15 new). My final table has 1000 rows (all old). We insert from staging, the 15 new rows only to the final table to make it 1015 rows.

**Expectation**: There has to be another table which will be loaded with 15 rows only after truncating whatever it had in the last run.

How can I achieve that?

The existing insert on conflict query is as follows:

```
insert into dev.active_data
(name, mobile, unique_identity, address, city)
select name, mobile, unique_identity, address, city
from dev.data_staging
on conflict on constraint unique_people do nothing
```

Here, unique_people constraint is as below:

```
ALTER TABLE dev.active_data
   ADD CONSTRAINT unique_people UNIQUE (mobile, unique_identity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres allows DML in a CTE. You use this converting your current INSERT into the CTE and also RETURNING what was just inserted. Then for the main create an INSERT for the new table. This works because when Postgres sees a duplicate it does nothing - including NOT RETURNING the indicated value. So: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=205e1aefe9662f3dab6c06ec60cd3f72))

```
with merged_data as 
    (insert into active_data
             (name, mobile, unique_identity, address, city)
      select name, mobile, unique_identity, address, city
        from data_stage
          on conflict on constraint unique_people do nothing
      returning *
    ) 
insert into new_active(name, mobile, unique_identity, address, city) 
  select name, mobile, unique_identity, address, city
    from merged_data;
```